# Why does the SAP User API for Hana cloud have a checkUserPassword method when you can't assign passwords in the cloud cockpit

Tags: sap-cloud-platform

SAPs User API for the HANA Cloud Platform, gives you the posibility to look up a user like this:

```
InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext();
UserProvider userProvider = (UserProvider) ctx.lookup("java:comp/env/user/Provider");       
user = userProvider.getUser(reqUser);
```

it also allows you to look up the assignt role ( for example Administrator)

```
user.hasRole("Administrator");
```

(untils this point everthing works fine)

and finally the password like this:

```
userProvider.checkUserPassword(username, userPasswordAsCharArray);
```

**The Question:**

Why does the checkUserPassword method even exists if there is no way to assign passwords to the users you can create in the Hana cloud cockpit?

(You can add a user to a group and assign a role to the user, but there is no password option)

Where is my mistake ?( I checked the Documentation and searched the web but couldn't find anything in 2 hours!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't create users via cloud cockpit. You only assign them application or account member roles and groups.

The UserProvider.checkUserPassword() method will by default check the password of the provided user against the SAP ID Service.

If you have configured an on-premise user store (see [OnPremise User Store](https://help.hana.ondemand.com/help/frameset.htm?04cbd0f30d524612aa438ed0b0eed217.html)) then the method will check the password agains the configured user store.

Comment: Okay thanks, sadly i cant test saps service with the developer account.